# Hook doesn't work with an third application

Tags: delphi, setwindowshookex

first, sorry about my english but I'm going to do my best.
I'd like to catch the BN_CLICKED notification attached to a specific button from a third application.
I'm able to find the handle button on the third application.
The code below works well when I change identication of the button to find with a button on my Application but not with another application !!!
Please tell me why because I'm going to be crasy.
Thank you in advance !

This is the DLL code :

```
{ WINHOOK.dll }
library Winhook;
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, vcl.dialogs, tlhelp32;
type
  TPMsg = ^TCWPSTruct;
var
  NextHook: HHOOK;
  hbutton: hwnd;
//---------------------------------------------------------
//fonction de remplacement pour le traitement du message
function MsgFilterFunc(Code: Integer; MwParam: Wparam;
                    MlParam: Lparam): LRESULT; stdcall;
begin
Result := 0;
if TPMsg(MlParam)^.message = WM_COMMAND then
  //si le handle correspond au bouton a surveiller
  if TPMsg(mlParam)^.lParam = hbutton then
    if hiword(TPMsg(mlParam)^.wParam)=BN_clicked then
          showmessage('BN_CLICKED Activé');

Result := CallNextHookEx(NextHook, Code, MwParam
                            ,MlParam);
end;
//---------------------------------------------------------
//Mise en place du hook avec WH_CALLWNDPROC pour interception
//des messages WM_COMMAND
function SetHook(hbt: hwnd; th: integer; MsgToSend: Integer):
                   Boolean; stdcall;
begin
  Result := False;
  hbutton := hbt;
  //hook sur le thread donné par th
  NextHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC,
            MsgFilterFunc, Hinstance,th);
  if NextHook <> 0 then Result := True;
end;
//---------------------------------------------------------
//Suppression du hook
function FreeHook: Boolean; stdcall;
begin
  Result := False;
  if UnHookWindowsHookEx(NextHook) then
    Result := true;
end;

exports
  SetHook ,
  FreeHook ;

begin
end.
```

This the programme code :

```
unit Uprogatester;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes,
  Graphics, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls, tlhelp32, ExtCtrls,
 Controls, ComCtrls;
const
  HookDemo = 'WINHOOK.dll';
const
  WM_HOOKCREATE = WM_USER + 300;
Type
  Pwindows = ^Twindows;
  Twindows = record
    windowhandle : hwnd;
    windowtext : string;
    windowclass : string;
   end;
Type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button2: TButton;
    BTNSETHook: TButton;
    BTNUNSETHook: TButton;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure BTNSETHookClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BTNUNSETHookClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure IDHandle;
  private
    FHookSet: Boolean;
    { Déclarations privées }
  public
    { Déclarations publiques }
  end;
var
  Form2: TForm2;
  IDProc: Tprocessentry32;
  IDThr: Tthreadentry32;
  processid,processhandle,threadid: cardinal;
  AWindows : PWindows;
  function SetHook(Hbt: hwnd; IDTh: integer; MsgToSend: Integer): Boolean;
                        stdcall; external HookDemo;
  function FreeHook: Boolean; stdcall; external HookDemo;
  function getclasstext(wnd:hwnd): boolean;
  function chercheboutonproc(wnd : hwnd;
                              Form : Tform2): bool;
                              {$ifdef win32} stdcall; {$endif}
  function enumwindowsproc(wnd : hwnd;
                        form : Tform2): bool;
                        {$ifdef win32} stdcall; {$endif}
implementation
{$R *.dfm}
//------------------------------------------------------
// recherche du bouton
function chercheboutonproc(wnd : hwnd;
                              Form : Tform2): bool;
                              {$ifdef win32} stdcall; {$endif}
begin
result := true;
if getclasstext(wnd) then
  if awindows^.windowclass = 'TButton'  then
  begin
    if awindows^.windowtext = 'Bouton a Tester' then
    begin
    result := false;
    end;
  end;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------
// recherche de la fenetre PARENT
function enumwindowsproc(wnd : hwnd;
                        form : Tform2): bool;
                        {$ifdef win32} stdcall; {$endif}
begin
result := true;
if getclasstext(wnd) then
  if awindows^.windowclass = 'TForm2'   then
  begin
    if awindows^.windowtext = 'Programme a tester' then
    begin
    enumchildwindows(wnd,@chercheboutonproc,0);
    result := false;
    end;
  end;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------
//Bouton Hook
procedure TForm2.BTNSETHookClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  enumwindows(@enumwindowsproc,longint(self));
  idhandle;
  showmessage(awindows^.WindowText+' / ' + awindows^.windowclass);
  FHookSet := LongBool(SetHook(awindows^.windowhandle,
                      threadID, WM_HOOKCREATE));
  if FHookSet then
  begin
    BTNSETHook.Enabled   := false;
    BTNUNSETHook.Enabled := true;
  end;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------
//Bouton UNHook
procedure TForm2.BTNUNSETHookClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FHookSet := FreeHook;
  if FHookSet then
  begin
    BTNSETHook.Enabled   := true;
    BTNUNSETHook.Enabled := false;
  end;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------
//Recherche handle ID processus et thread
procedure TForm2.IDHandle;
var shothdl: Thandle;
begin
//pour trouver une numero d'id d'un processus
IDProc.dwSize := sizeof(IDProc);
shothdl := createtoolhelp32snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
try
  if shothdl=-1 then exit;
  if process32first(shothdl,IDProc) then
  begin
    while process32next(shothdl,IDProc) do
    begin
      if (ansisametext(IDProc.szExeFile,'winhook.dll')) then
      begin
        processid := IDProc.th32ProcessID;
      end;
    end;
  end;
finally closehandle(shothdl);
end;
//pour trouver le numero d'id du thread correspondant
IDThr.dwSize := sizeof(IDThr);
shothdl := createtoolhelp32snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
try
  if shothdl=-1 then exit;
  if thread32first(shothdl,IDThr) then
  begin
    while thread32next(shothdl,IDThr) do
    begin
      if IDThr.th32OwnerProcessID=processid then
      begin
        threadid := IDThr.th32ThreadID;
      end;
    end;
  end;
finally closehandle(shothdl);
end;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
FHookSet := false;
btnsethook.Enabled := true;
btnunsethook.Enabled := false;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------
procedure TForm2.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BTNUNSETHook.Click;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------
//recupération a chaque enumérartion
function getclasstext(wnd:hwnd): boolean;
var
  buffer : array[0..99] of char;
  nomclass : array[0..255] of char;
begin
result := true;
getclassname(wnd,nomclass,256);
getwindowtext(wnd,buffer,100);
new(awindows);
awindows^.windowhandle := wnd;
awindows^.windowtext := strpas(buffer);
awindows^.windowclass := strpas(nomclass);
end;

end.
```

[problem when I execute with the third application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peNx6.png)

Comment: Your enumeration code is leaking memory, and skipping the 1st process and 1st thread reported by `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`. You should also consider using `SetWinEventHook()` instead of `SetWindowsHookEx()`. No DLL is needed, and you can filter events more efficiently.

Comment: Also, the way you are determining the thread ID to hook to needlessly complicated. You can use `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` inside your `Enum(Child)Windows()` callbacks to help you filter windows. `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` should be used only to get the desired process ID, if used at all. Given just the process ID, you can enumerate windows belonging to the process, and given identification you can filter for the specific button, and then get its thread ID directly.

Comment: You have to pass 0 for thread identifier to SetWindowsHookEx for a global hook. Granted, I don't exactly know what "IDThr.th32ThreadID" is but I assume it's not returning 0.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz the OP doesn't need a global hook in this situation.  A thread-specific hook will work just fine, provided the OP obtains the correct thread ID to hook. A DLL is still needed when hooking a thread in another process, though.

Comment: @Remy, Ok, thanks. @ Franck - I would then suggest adding some error handling for api calls, that would help with the "why".

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set hook on button itself, but [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bn-clicked) says, that WM_COMMAND is sent to the **parent** of the button. So you should set hook on the parent.

Comment: I don't know the language but the error message says something like "could not write memory".

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Novice users often show screenshots for a different version of the code, than the one in their question.